# Update query using IIf() in a WHERE condition

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, iif

I am writing an update query in Access which is based on a make table query.

In my temporary table (the output of my make table query), I have 3 fields [Tick], [DivLevel4] and [T]. I can have identical Ticks displaying different values for [DivLevel4] if [T] bears different values (only C or F):

```
Tick    DivLevel4  T

AA      5          C
AA      0          F
BB      2          C
CC      3          C
CC      0          F
```

How can I incorporate this condition in my update query? I have tried adding an `IIf()` statement in the criteria field but it is not doing the job:

```
IIf([tblTrades].[T]="Y",0,[tbl_DIV_Temp].[[DivLevel4])
```

as in

```
UPDATE 
    tblTrades 
    INNER JOIN 
    tbl_DIV_Temp 
        ON tblTrades.Tick = tbl_DIV_Temp.Tick 
SET tblTrades.DIV = [tbl_DIV_Temp].[DivLevel4]
WHERE (((tblTrades.DIV)=IIf([tblTrades].[T]="F",0,[tbl_DIV_Temp].[DivLevel4])));
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just run two update statements to cover the two different conditions? I'm not sure if what you're trying to do is possible. Another option would be to use DLookup to get the value of tbl_Div_Temp.DivLevel4 and then use the raw value (using a variable) in your Update Statement.

Comment: Are you asking how to set `tblTrades.DIV = tbl_DIV_Temp.DivLevel4` when `tblTrades.T = "F"`?

Comment: Or do you intend (as your if statement implies) to "Set tblTrades.DIV = tbl_DIV_Temp.Tick unless tblTrades.T = "F", in which case set tblTrades.DIV = 0"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Topic is close. Alternative method found.